# Bind text box of report to cell of the table in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

In MS Access I need to bind text field to cell of the table (in report). How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new report
2. On the New Report window (assuming Design View is selected in the pick-list), select the relevant table table.
3. Click OK
4. Open the Field List window
5. Drag-n-drop the relevant field onto the report.

You can also do the same thing with Queries.

If the report already exists, you can change the report's record source to the table (or a query) in the properties window, and then drag-n-drop fields on the report the same way.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to set the row source of the report to the table, then set the data source of the text field to the column you require.

That will do what you ask for but there is more to access report than that. Perhaps you can clarify what you are trying to do.